# pycharm to use a conda environment

Tags: python, pycharm, conda

I am trying to add a conda environment to a pycharm project.
I am following the below steps:

1. Creating a new conda environment using the commands as below:

conda create --name pennylane_study python=3.8 numpy

2. Activating the conda environment:

   conda activate pennylane_study
3. Checking the locating on my pennylane_env

(pennylane_study) PS C:\Users\m992c693> conda env list
conda environments:

base                     C:\Users\m992c693\AppData\Local\anaconda3
Dugrasoft_study

C:\Users\m992c693\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\Dugrasoft_study
pennylane_study       *  C:\Users\m992c693\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\pennylane_study

5. Installing pycharm community version.
6. Creating a new project.
7. Selecting a previously configured project, as shown below:
   [image]
8. Clicking Add interpreter
9. Selecting conda Environment and then looking for its location as shown below:
   [image]
   [image]

Inside the pennylane_study folder, I expected to find a bin folder and python.exe file but nothing like that exists. I was trying to take help of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1SFlh-pW_Q but folders looks different in my system.
Need help in configuring the pycharm with a conda environment.I am working on windows OS and  `which python` command does not work on my system.
Thank you.

**Edit**
I am not sure why this problem I am facing on my lab system. I just tried to do the similar thing on my laptop, I am able to find the python.exe file. But I still have a question. What is this conda executable?
[image]

Comment: Did you try conda.exe in the scripts folder as the executable? https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/ide-tutorials/pycharm/

Comment: Thank you @topsail for the response. There is nothing in my Scripts folder.

Comment: Hi @topsail, when I navigate to the folder of my env (pennylane_study), there is a python.exe file, but it doesnot show up when I try to find it through pycharm. What should I do?

Comment: How about create a new conda environment in pycharm and then see how it works from that example?

Comment: Hi @topsoil, I tried the creating the installation my laptop, I am able to find the python.exe file. I have edited the question.  But I still do not understand what it means by conda executable?

Comment: @topsail Even after adding interpretor, pycharm says "No interpretor". Not sure why?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLl1tXoaNgk   This video is useful to know how to add iterpreter to the project.  My problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Conda executable is the program you ran when you entered `conda create --name pennylane_study python=3.8 numpy` command on the command prompt. This conda.exe (on Windows) resides in your Anaconda installation directory/folder. On the screenshots you attached you can see PyCharm recognised the anaconda installation in your user folder on your laptop. `env` and `Scripts` folders usually live in the same parent folder.

However, on your school pc Anaconda seems to be installed on a different location and PyCharm cannot find this directory. From the screenshots attached we can see the that the conda environment is in your appdata folder.

To manually locate the Anaconda installation, open Anaconda command prompt and enter `set` command. See the screenshot below. You can enter this path on PyCharm.

[image]

Also, python.exe lives in the root of the env folder. not inside a `bin` sub-folder.
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Kaveen Perera for the response. Suppose my anaconda3 is installed at /user/manu/AppData/Local, then in which folder should I install Pycharm.  By default, when I am installing Pycharm, it gives me a path /user/manu/AppData/JetBrains/Pycharm Community Edition 2023.2.1?

Comment: @mchaudh4 There is no strict rule where the program should be installed. /user/manu/AppData/ resided within your user folder, this is where many programs install when you use 'just for me' option and only you can run the software from this location, other users can't. When you install for all users software usually go to 'C:\Program Files' folder. Some software likes to create its own folder on the root of system drive (usually the C drive) for various reasons. If your school as provides a fast network drive you can install it there as well, so you can access it on any lab PC.